# Selecting rows based on latest timestamp

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a question about tables, as I am new to it if any help that would be great.

I have a table with 3 columns. I use the first column out of it to make it as the common key. Based on the key I may get multiple rows selected. I would like to select the row with the latest timestamp which is column 2. Column 3 can have different values.

Eg:

```
Col1          Col2       Col3 
some_name     12:5:12   1
some_name     12:6:12   0
some_name1    12:5:12   1
some_name1    12:6:12   0
some_name2    12:5:12   0
some_name2    12:6:12   1
```

Output:

```
Col1          Col2       Col3 
some_name     12:6:12   0
some_name1    12:6:12   0
some_name2    12:6:12   1
```

I would like to do this in apache spark.

Answer (score 2):

In Spark, I think I would go for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sparks `Window functions`:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy(col("col2").desc)

df.withColumn("latestTS", row_number().over(w))
  .where(col("latestTS") === 1)
  .drop("latestTS")
  .show(false)

+----------+-------+----+
|col1      |col2   |col3|
+----------+-------+----+
|some_name |12:6:12|0   |
|some_name1|12:6:12|0   |
|some_name2|12:6:12|1   |
+----------+-------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

this query may help you

```
select
*
from table ta
where ta.col2 = (select MAX(col2) from table  where col1 = ta.col1)
```

this query returan latest data for col1