# Pyspark when based in countDistinct condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following scenario: A dataframe with payment informations like bill id number, client id, bill's value, date of payment, etc. In this DF the same client can have N bills with the same bill_id each. So,  I want to:

- Make an in evaluation to check if some **bill_id** appears more than 1 time for the customer;
- **If yes**, I want to keep only the most recent record using **timestamp criteria**;
- **If not**, I want to select the unique record for that **bill_id**.
- The result will be stored in a new DF from a **df.where** clause

I tried the following code with no success:

```py
df_clients_bills = df_clients_bills.where(
  when(countDistinct(df_clients_bills.bill_id) > 1, max(df_clients_bills.payment_date)).otherwise(df_clients_bills)
)
```

I don't know if this is the best approach to solve the question. Any tip which can lead to the solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting rows based on latest timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684873/selecting-rows-based-on-latest-timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL to accomplish this:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Just a basic example
df_pd = pd.DataFrame({
    "bill_id": [1, 1, 1],
    "payment_date": [
        datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(3)],
    "value": [1, 2, 3]
})
df_clients_bills = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)
df_clients_bills.registerTempTable("df_clients_bills")
query = """
    SELECT
        df_clients_bills.bill_id,
        df_clients_bills.payment_date,
        df_clients_bills.value
    FROM df_clients_bills
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT bill_id, MAX(payment_date) AS max_payment_date
        FROM df_clients_bills
        GROUP BY bill_id
    ) AS bill_id_max_dates
    ON 
        (df_clients_bills.bill_id = bill_id_max_dates.bill_id) AND
        (df_clients_bills.payment_date = bill_id_max_dates.max_payment_date)
"""
result = spark.sql(query)
result.show(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you actually don't need to distinguish between distinct counts values, because the "take most recent bill" if there is several bills also works if there is only one bill.

So, what you can do is use a [window function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/) to rank bills having the same id from max timestamp to min timestamp and then select the first line of each group, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df_clients_bills = df_clients_bills \
    .withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('bill_id').orderBy(F.desc('payment_date')))) \
    .filter(F.col('row_number') == 1) \
    .drop('row_number')
```